# Handling APNS Push Token with no network connectivity

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Most documentation advises to register for remote notifications on launch, and on receipt of the token, push this to a server with any other app-specific settings (e.g. user, in-app Push settings). However, I am not sure how to handle the following corner case.

If the user launches the app without connectivity, no token will be received. Moments later, connectivity is restored. The user attempts to change some setting in the app, which should prompt a post to my server including the setting and the token. However, the token is still nil.

Would it not be better, instead, to register for notifications every time before attempting to post the setting? It seems unnecessary to request this token on launch since it might not be needed, and even worse, might be nil when it **is** needed.

Comment: I say, keep it simple. Only send the token on launch. If you want to additionally send settings at other times, do so, but don't include the token.

Comment: What if all I have is the token? I.e. there is no concept of the 'user' other than the token? Even with a User, I would be storing settings against a user with no associated token. The user would expect to receive notifications based on his settings but nothing would arrive. Until he happened to launch the app again (and assuming it was closed in the interim) at which point the token will be received for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's still best to register for push notifications when the app is launched. When you get the device token, you don't have to immediately send it to your server. You can store it locally on the device. When your logic requires to send the device token (as well as other settings) to your server, get the locally saved token. If the saved token is null, try registering again, and send the token to your server once you get it.

Note that when the app is launched you should register for push notifications even if you a have a previous locally stored device token (due to the remote chance that Apple would decide to change the device token).

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I'm leaning. Still not sure of the benefit of getting a token on launch though if I'm sometimes going to also request it before posting settings. Might as well just get it when its needed (and also check if its changed at the same point)?

Comment: @BenPackard Getting the token on launch increases the chances it would be available when you need to send it to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends you should call register every time the app comes to the foreground ( either when you open it or when it comes back from background).

This call does not serve only as a way to get the push notification token but also to let Apple know that this application is still interested in receiving push notification. If you call this method only once, or rarely and you don't send push notifications that often, you could run into a scenario where the token you have been using, that is stored on the server is no longer a valid token (after enough time has passed without a token being acknowledged by a device apple will no longer consider the token valid. )